# Getting Fatal Python error running Django on Apache

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, apache

I am trying to deploy my Django app through a Digital Ocean droplet server using Ubuntu 22.04 and MySQL. When I try to run the app through Apache, I get a "Forbidden Access" message. I checked the error log and see this error (I have removed my username from the directories):

```
Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=983): Unable to stat Python home /home///mm_venv. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/home///mm_venv'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/home//mm_venv'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/home//mm_venv'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '//mm_venv'
  sys.exec_prefix = '//mm_venv'
  sys.path = [
    '/home//mm_venv/lib/python310.zip',
    '/home//mm_venv/lib/python3.10',
    '/home//mm_venv/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

This is my etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf file:

```
 ServerName example.com
 ServerAlias www.example.com
 ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
 DocumentRoot /home//mommind_new

 Alias /static /home//mommind_new/static
    <Directory /home//mommind_new/static>
       Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home//mommind_new/mmdigiocean>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
WSGIDaemonProcess mommind_new python-home=/home//mommind_new/mm_venv python-path=/home//mommind_new

WSGIProcessGroup mommind_new

WSGIScriptAlias / /home//mommind_new/mmdigiocean/wsgi.py
```

These look correct to me, so I am really at a loss. Can someone please help me solve this issue?

Comment: And what are the permissions for `mod_wsgi` and all directories in the path.

Comment: @michjnich all permissions are granted (see the 000-default.conf file above). Is there someplace else I should be looking?

Comment: I see the config, but what about the actual dir and file permissions on on the path to mod_wsgi. Have you checked them?

Comment: I have yet to check them; I am new to this, can you please let me know where those files are usually located?

Comment: @michjnich can you please provide a bit more on how I can check the actual dir and file permissions?